# Initializing arrays, potentially unforseen consequences?

Tags: arrays, string, c++11, cin

I've recently observed that by initializing an array, the garbage values are **all** replaced by null terminators. This would appear to be inconsequential, but in a large program I don't think it would be preferable to spend resources on cleaning out an array. Now to be clear, I don't program large programs, that's why I'm asking, I'm just a beginner. However, when used properly, it would stand to reason that garbage values would be perfectly fine as long as there is always an explicitly placed terminator.

So then, should I take it as bible to always initialize my arrays, or should I consider whether I can get away with leaving the garbage values untouched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's part of the C++ spec<sup>1</sup>, §11.6.2, which discusses the behavior of initializing character (or wide character) arrays using string literals:

> If there are fewer initializers than there are array elements, each element not explicitly initialized shall be
>   zero-initialized (11.6).

Anyway, regarding computational cost:

When you initialize an array in global (not function scope), it would typically land in the `.data` segment of your executable and be initialized by copying pages of memory straight from the executable image, rather than instructions that poke bytes of memory at a time during initialization. Either the page is copied as the program is loaded, or it's [demand-paged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging), again at a page-level granularity.

In this case, since the entirety of the storage must be initialized, there's no additional cost to specifically initialize it with zeros.

<sup>1</sup> I can't find a good non-paywalled copy of the official spec. This quote is taken from a [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf), on page 228 (per page footers) or page 242 (per PDF pagination).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! But what is this executable "image", that's not terminology I've hard before, I've tried to Wikipedia it, but I'm not even sure what I'm looking for. . . . I'm super interested in learning the architecture of programs, and computers of course, so I really don't want to miss anything. There wouldn't be a really convenient place for learning it all that you're aware of would there be?

Comment: @GoodBoy The executable image is simply the file that is run by the operating system. I'm working based off Linux terminology/concepts; in the Linux case it's the `a.out` file (or simply executable file) that `g++` outputs. For Windows, it would be the .exe file, but I'm not sure if Windows uses the same mapping/page copying to initialize segments of memory. I haven't had a chance to peruse it in depth, but [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) might shed some more info regarding how Windows does this.

Comment: Just a note on the standard: ISO is careful to get paid for the official standards, but you can find in  https://github.com/cplusplus/draft.git what has been released, follow the development in detail and generate latest versions. May be slightly scary at first glance for a beginner, but it gives a useful idea how things work.